# Getting the correct info from an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse this XML document:
http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=3332

I have this class:

```
public class Episode {
  public int Season { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

My code:

```
string path = "http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=" + id;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
```

Now I'm stuck. How can I create a list of episodes from this file? I'm confused because of the attribute used for the Season.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var episodes = doc.SelectNodes(@"/Show/Episodelist/Season/episode");
List<Episode> episodesList = new List<Episode>();
foreach (XmlNode episode in episodes)
{
    episodesList.Add(new Episode()
    {
        Season = Int32.Parse(episode.ParentNode.Attributes["no"].Value.ToString()),
        Title = episode.SelectNodes("title")[0].InnerText
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about trying Linq To Xml?

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=3332");

var name = xDoc.Root.Element("name").Value;
var episodes = xDoc.Descendants("episode")
                    .Select(e => new
                    {
                        epnum = (string)e.Element("epnum"),
                        //seasonnum = (string)e.Element("seasonnum"),
                        seasonnum = (string)e.Parent.Attribute("no"),
                        prodnum = (string)e.Element("prodnum"),
                        airdate = (string)e.Element("airdate"),
                        link = (string)e.Element("link"),
                        title = (string)e.Element("title"),
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564) is a simple tutorial, it may be helpful.
It describes how to get elements from an xml file.

After that, You only need to make a `List<Episode>` and fill it with the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = @"http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid="+id;
IEnumerable<Episode> Episodes =XDocument.Load(path)
        .Descendants("episode")
        .Select(x => new Episode
        {

            Season = Convert.ToInt16(x.Element("seasonnum").Value),
            Title = x.Element("title").Value
        });
```